# PHP checking if username in multiple tables

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to check if a passed in username is in either one of 3 tables. If it is then it exists and will return true, or else it will return false. Currently it just returns true no matter what.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 INNER JOIN Table3 WHERE Table1.username = :name OR Table2.username = :name OR Table3.username = :name");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST["username"] );
$num_rows = $stmt->execute();

if ($num_rows > 0) 
   {
    echo "true";
   }
 else
    {
    echo "false";
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `$num_rows`?  From the looks of the query, it's not going to be an integer.  It's going to be a set of matching records.  I imagine that object itself will always evaluate to `true` or `> 0`.

Comment: why are you joining the tables? there are no appearant reasons to join 3 tables without any condition.  why don't you run 3 seperate queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's way better to use UNION in that case.

```
$sql = 'SELECT 1 FROM Table1 WHERE username = :name
        UNION
        SELECT 1 FROM Table2 WHERE username = :name
        UNION
        SELECT 1 FROM Table3 WHERE username = :name';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $_POST["username"] );
$qry = $stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
  // no match
} else {
  // match
}
```

Comment: Assuming this is PDO, [$stmt->execute](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) return a bool not a result set object.